# Animate layout changes in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

In an Android App I can define transitions when I know that a View will change its height. That change will then be animated. How can I do something similar with a Column in Flutter? I know of AnimatedContainer, but that only seems to work with specific height values that I have to set. Is there an equivalent to "animatelayoutchanges" in Flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap you column **children** in a `SizeTransition`. The idea is to have each child animate its appearance and disappearance.

You create one `AnimationController` per `SizeTransition` and when you want to show or hide a child, you simply call `AnimationController.forward()` or `reverse()`

Comment: You could write a simple practical example demonstrating how it works.